# Issue with Start-ThreadJob ScriptBlock Unable to find powershell script

Tags: multithreading, powershell, powershell-module

I am using Start-ThreadJob and ScriptBlock to execute a powershell script in a new thread. It works fine on my local but on the preprod server, I am getting an error.

**Code Block where I am initiating a new thread**

```
Start-ThreadJob -InputObject $fileType -ScriptBlock {
          ./Functions/Download-FilesFromFTP.ps1 $args[0] $args[1]  $args[2] $args[3] $args[4] $args[5]
        } -ArgumentList $ftpServer,$user,$password,$completeSourceFolder,$completeStagingFolderPath,$completeLogFolderPath
```

As mentioned earlier, this code block works perfectly on my local. On Preprod env I get the following error when I display jobs using Get-Jobs command.
[image]

**Powershell version on my local**
[image]

**Powershell version on preprod server**
[image]

The version of the module ThreadJob is same on both servers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Start-ThreadJob` runs the new thread with the same current location as the caller, which is unrelated to where the executing script is located.

If you want to refer to a file relative to the *script's own location*, use the [automatic `$PSScriptRoot` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psscriptroot), and refer to it in the thread script block via the [`$using:` scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes#the-using-scope-modifier):

```
Start-ThreadJob -InputObject $fileType -ScriptBlock {
  & "$using:PSScriptRoot/Functions/Download-FilesFromFTP.ps1" @args
} -ArgumentList $ftpServer,$user,$password,$completeSourceFolder,$completeStagingFolderPath,$completeLogFolderPath
```

Note the use of `@args` in order to also pass all positional arguments, reflected in the [automatic `$args` array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args), through as individual arguments to the target script via [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting).

Comment: If this was the problem, how is this script working on my local? Thanks for your response though, I will try to implement what u r saying

Comment: @TarunBhatt, it would only work on your local machine _if the current location (`$pwd`) happens to be the same location in which your script is located_ - assuming that `./Functions/Download-FilesFromFTP.ps1` is relative to where your script is located.

Comment: I think I get what you are saying. When the script was working on my local, its running from a terminal within VSCode but when I run the same script on my local from a separate Powershell command prompt, it gives the same error. I will go through ur solution again and implement ur advice

Comment: Although I am now able to simulate the issue on my local by using an independent powershell console instead of VSCode terminal, I still don't why is this an issue. The pwd command from both locations return the same location

Comment: @TarunBhatt, you don't need to solve this mystery if you know that the relative path `./Functions/Download-FilesFromFTP.ps1` should be relative _to the enclosing script file's location_. If that is indeed the intent, the only reliable way to invoke this path is via `$PSScriptRoot`.

Comment: This worked. Although not the ideal solution. Your original comment on this post would be the way to go and I will learn and implement it that way